# Disable AJAX request until finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a slightly modded jQuery Autocomplete plugin,

it's simply changed to fetch a JSON object from a MySQL database instead of some array.

However, I noticed that upon clicking the input field, it would send a new request, the same as the previous..
And if I clicked again another, and many many quick clicks quickly started shaping a horrible problem... There's nothing stopping it from sending an unlimited amount of requests per second.

SO, since I send the request to a specific place, and that place should Never handle the Same request twice,
how can I stop it from sending a new request if the input field contains the same string as last request?

And this is where I got the modified plugin from:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: "By click"!! can you show us some code? are you attaching the ajax on `Click` event on the input field instead on `change` event?! also why using a deprecated plugin anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a mutex semphore in, just a flag that knows whether or not a request is actively in progress, so that instead of triggering a new request, you check if there is an active request and only proceed if not.

```
var inProgress = false;

$('selector').click(function() {
  if (!inProgress) {
     inProgress = true;
     ajaxRoutine();
  }
});

function ajaxRoutine() {
   ...
   inProgress = false;
   return;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `inProgress` to false on an error condition as well.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: Well, any exit condition at all needs to set the flag.